# How to change storage from local cache to database in keycloak with info about session

Tags: keycloak

I have a file cache-owners.cli and there are lines in it:

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=clientSessions: write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT:1})
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=keycloak/distributed-cache=offlineClientSessions: write-attribute(name=owners, value=${env.CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT:1})
```

How can I change the storage from a local cache to a database (for example, PostgreSql) with information about current sessions

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak use infinispan as cache. in default deployment the keycloak node itself act as in-memory infinispan node.

So you have 2 options.

1. config store into db(e.g. redis)
2. the more practical one: deploy external infinispan cluster and config keycloak to use remote-cache.